# htaccess to remove .php .html extension if exists from URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have pages like the following

- http://www.domain.com/p.php?p=InfoPages&file=about.php
- http://www.domain.com/p.php?p=InfoPages&file=contact
- http://www.domain.com/p.php?p=InfoPages&file=post.html

I want to change them to

- http://www.domain.com/page/about
- http://www.domain.com/page/contact
- http://www.domain.com/page/post

> RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /p.php?p=InfoPages&file=$1

I am currently using the above code in .htaccess but it doesn't work if there is a .php or .html extension in the url.

I've googled for this but still i can't find a perfect way to solve since not all links have extensions.
please advise. thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work with the extension? The rule itself or your PHP? What exactly do you want it to do? Remove the extension or just send the matching value to your php?

Comment: i am looking for the rule, @PanamaJack

Comment: Im not sure that answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /p\.php\?p=([^&]+)&file=([^.]+)\.php|html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%2? [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /p.php?p=InfoPages&file=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```